# Running CUDA kernel on CPU

Tags: compiler, gpu, nvidia

Is there a compiler that can compile CUDA kernels to an executable running on CPU? Even if it is not accelerated and just a simulation, (for example threads run sequentially until the next synchronize, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any. The best you can do is just copy the kernel and loop it for the block size you are running on CPU.